# Does the 'use' keyword in PHP trigger the spl_autoload_register()?

Tags: php, namespaces

I know `spl_autoload_register()` is called when a new instance of a class is encountered in the code - that isn't already included.

But does using the `use` keyword for namespaces trigger `spl_autoload_register()`, or anything similar?

Comment: If you are looking to TRIGGER an autoload just by having "use Some\Namespace;" ... nope.